# How to use another js in mithril.js

Tags: mithril.js

I need to include a third-party js library in my website and a working example in plain HTML file is something like

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script>App.initialize();</script>
```

Basically the initialize() function will first fill the `#app` with a loading animation then fetch data from external API and finally load the `#app` with html code it generated.

Everything works fine until I rewrite it in mithril.js, something like

```
const page = {
  view: () => [
    m('script', {src: 'app.js'}),
    m(app)
  ]
} 
const app = {
  oncreate: () => { App.initialize();},  
  view: () => m('#app')
}
```

When I render the `page`, I can still see the loading animation but after it is gone, nothing shows up in `#app`.  The expected code is not loaded in `#app` as in plain HTML file, and there is no error message in the console.

Did I miss anything or do anything wrong in mithril.js?

Comment: There could be a timing issue where the script is not finished loading.  Can you load the script outside the mithril code to guarantee it is  loaded? Also are you mounting your mithril app on the body tag because if the app.js code is loading things into the body it might be conflicting.

Comment: @IanWilson What do you mean by "load the script outside the mithril code"? The script works well in plain HTML code.  The mithril app is mounted on the body but I think the app.js should only affect the `#app` div, do you think it still matters?

Comment: The script might load synchronously when in the html but async when injected.  I'm not sure if that is browser dependent or not.  If it is deferred or async then some functionality might not work like document.write, etc. that would work if it is parsed on load.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be some sort of timing issue with loading the script that way.  Also if it puts things into the body element then mithril might re-render over it.  Maybe try something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/mithril/mithril.js"></script>
        <div id="page"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         let appLoaded = false;
         let mithrilLoaded = false;
         let appTimer = null;
         let mithrilTimer = null;
         function stopSync() {
             console.log('Sync done, init app.')
             appLoaded = mithrilLoaded = true;
             window.clearInterval(appTimer);
             window.clearInterval(mithrilTimer);
             appTimer = mithrilTimer = null;
             App.initialize();
         }
         function startAppSync() {
             console.log('App loaded, start sync with mithril.')
             appLoaded = true;
             appTimer = window.setInterval(checkAppSync, 100);
         }
         function startMithrilSync() {
             console.log('Mithril loaded, start sync with app.')
             mithrilLoaded = true;
             mithrilTimer = window.setInterval(checkMithrilSync, 100);
         }
         function checkAppSync() {
             console.log('Checking mithril from app sync.')
             if (mithrilLoaded) {
                 stopSync();
             }
         }
         function checkMithrilSync() {
             console.log('Checking app from mithril sync.')
             if (appLoaded) {
                 stopSync();
             }
         }
         const page = {
             view: function() {
                 return m('', [
                     m('script', {
                         onload: function () {
                             startAppSync();
                         },
                         src:'app.js'
                     }),
                     m(app),
                 ]);
             }
         }
         const app = {
             oncreate: function() {
                 startMithrilSync();
             },
             view: function() {
                 return m('#app');
             }
         }

         m.mount(document.getElementById('page'), page);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

More information here, the scripts injected are loaded async by default.  You can test this in browser with  `document.createElement('script').async`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#dynamically_importing_scripts